# Adding image uploader to TinyMCE in CakePHP giving errors

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, codeigniter, cakephp

I am using a tinyMCE plugin for uploading an image into tinyMCE http://justboil.me/. This plugin is developed using codeignitor.

I just tried implementing it with a test php file and its working fine but when I upload the code into cakephp ie in the app/webroot/js/editor/tinymce.

The error that I get is URL NOT FOUND http://mysite.com/js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english

The above url is the same url(the relative URL) that works from my localhost when used with a simple php file.

I think this can be an issue relating the htaccess file in the webroot folder of cakephp.

This is my htacess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the correct URL for image uploader?

Comment: http://mysite.com/js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english I think this is the correct url because localhost/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english works fine for me in the local server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this edit to your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !tinymce index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This one also not working. I have found one more thing just now ie the url is working till the constructor in the uploader.php(a controller in codeignitor). 'upload' is a function in the controller 'uploader' the function 'upload' is not being accessed ie the problem.

Comment: Run your page in Firebug and see which URL is throwing 404 error.

Comment: http://dev3.1whp.com/js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/blank and http://dev3.1whp.com/js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english

Comment: Can you check whether there is another .htaccess anywhere in your system and if there is any other other code in this .htaccess

Comment: This is a cakephp application there are many htaccess file. I found a working url for the same function ie http://dev3.1whp.com/app/webroot/js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload can you identify htaccess in which folder do i need to edit?

Comment: If there is any .htaccess under `/js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/` ?

Comment: No there is no htaccess under /js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/ but under /js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/applications and /js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/system there are htaccess saying "Deny from all" .

I like to add a thing I solved the issue using direct url ie the full path "http://mysite.com/app/webroot/js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english" this is not the right way the corret url in cakephp should be http://mysite.com/js/editor/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english